# Placing values into variables perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string like this

```
destination: 29231, 280646, 9.715e-2, 60, 109
```

and I'm trying to place each number into variables

```
if ($i =~ m/^destination:\s(\d+)\,\s(\d+)\,\s(\d+\.\d+\e-\d+)\,\s(\d+)\,\s(\d+)/){
$num1 = $1;
$num2 = $2;
$num3 = $3;
$num4 = $4;
$num5 = $5;
}
```

seems `\s(\d+\.\d+\e-\d+)\` is not working, where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why `\e`? Should be just `e`.

Comment: You are escaping tooooooooo much. Don't just escape on a whim. Anyways, escaping the `e` letter will cause it to match [ASCII 27 (ESC)](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/escape-ascii-code-27.html). I suggest to use `^destination\s*:\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+\.\d+e-\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)` for the moment

Comment: Why escape the e and the comma? Are you sure you want to be that specific in each capture group?

Comment: "e" is a number in power of that value, its not a regexp and it must be in the variable, like $num3 must be exactly 9.715e-2

Comment: @Rocker [This is what might happen](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5Ct%5Ce%5Cs%5Ct) when you escape too much

Comment: #HamZa, oh i see, so i must write it in this way \s(\d+\.\d+\w\-\d+)\

Comment: @Rocker There is no need to escape a hyphen `-` outside a character class.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

found it, just made mistake on \e,

correct expression should be this: `\s(\d+\.\d+\w-\d+)\`

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Why is that, then?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Then I think you should delete your comment. I am very worried that it got five upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

A better way of doing this is to use the split function. Here, you can split up the string into elements separated by spaces (`\s+`), and print them out (or rename them, or whatever) if they are digits (`/^\d+/`).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'destination: 29231, 280646, 9.715e-2, 60, 109';

my @split = split(/\s+/, $string);

foreach (@split){
    s/,//; # get rid of commas
    print "$_\n" if /^\d+/;
}
```

Prints:

```
29231
280646
9.715e-2
60
109
```

Comment: Whenever you write `split /\s+/, $string`, you almost certainly want `split ' ', $string` instead. If the target string starts with white space then the former will give you an empty string as the first element of the returned list, whereas the latter will not.

Comment: It's the first thing I thought of when I saw it. However, I would first do `$string =~ s/destination:\s*//;` to get rid of the prefix and then `split /,\s*/ $string;`

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends on exactly how your strings are formatted, but you can just find all fields that aren't whitespace or comma and drop the first one, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'destination: 29231, 280646, 9.715e-2, 60, 109';

my @numbers = $string =~ /[^\s,]+/g;
shift @numbers;

print "$_\n" for @numbers;
```

**output**

```
29231
280646
9.715e-2
60
109
```